# Finding total video minutes on a YouTube channel with API

Tags: api, video, youtube, analytics

I need to calculate the total number of minutes featured on a specific YouTube channel (not viewing minutes). That includes uploaded videos (which I know how to find) AND videos within playlists (without duplicates).

So, the channel can have videos from other channels in any number of its playlists; but I want to calculate the total minutes of video featured on the channel. This would be: uploaded videos plus other videos added to the channel's playlists.

Any ideas?